# Are groups with this property already studied?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $\Omega$ be a finite group, let $G$ be a subgroup of $\Omega$ and let $S$ be a set of subgroups of $\Omega$ such that for $H, H'\in S$ we have $H\cap H' \in S$ and $\langle H, H' \rangle \in S$.

One can show that if $GH = GH'$ then also $GH = G\langle H, H' \rangle$. So given $H \in S$ we can find $H_{\max}\in S$ such that $G H = G H_{\max}$ and $H_{\max}$ is maximal with that property.

We say $H_{\max}$ is $G$-maximal in $S$. One can also show that if $G\cap H = G\cap H'$ then also $G\cap H = G\cap (H\cap H')$.

So given $H\in S$ we can find $H_{\min} \in S$ such that $G\cap H = G\cap H_{\min}$ and $H_{\min}$ is minimal with that property. We say $H_{\min}$ is $G$-minimal in $S$.

In the context of my work I'm interested in groups in $S$ that are $G$-minimal and $G$-maximal at the same time. One can show that they always exist.

So my question is:

> What properties do such groups have and is there any literature for this?

An example would be if $\Omega= S_4$, $G = D_8$ and $S$ are all Young-subgroups in $S_4$. Then the groups that are $D_8$-maximal and $D_8$-minimal in $S$ are eaxactly the $S_4$ and all $V_4$'s in $S$.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Shaun What would you suggest as a title here?

Comment: I don't know, @the_fox. That's a good question. I think the OP is in a better position to be concise here than I am.

Comment: I suspect there are more interesting results if you put restrictions on $S$ - if we allow $S$ to be a singleton $S=\{H\}$ then any subgroup $H$ is trivially $G$-maximal or $G$-minimal in $S=\{H\}$, whereas if $S$ is all subgroups of $\Omega$ then $H$ is $G$-minimal in $S$ iff $H\le G$ so $H$ is both $G$-minimal and $G$-maximal in $S$ iff $H=G$

Comment: Yes for the 2 trivial examples the answer is clear. Im particularly interested in the case where $\Omega = S_n$ and $S$ is the set of all Young-subgroups. The following properties can be proven about a group $H$ that is $G$-minimal and $G$-maximal: (1) $H$ is uniquely determined by the sets $GH$ and $G\cap H$, (2) $H$ is uniquely determined by $GH$ or $G\cap H$ if we know that it is $G$-minimal and $G$-maximal, (3) $H$ always exists, (4) $N(G)$ acts on $G$-minimal and $G$-maximal groups.

Comment: This question was endorsed in [the Pearl Dive](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102837/pearl-dive) by Alexander Gruber. I'm simply checking out old stuff offered there. Plans for redesigning that place are being drawn, but we can use more material.